# Validation based on parent data in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Assume I have a database with products:

| Id | Name | MaxSpeed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | Lite | 100 |
| 41 | Basic | 500 |
| 42 | Premium | 1000 |

And assume we sell services based on these products. These services can be configured for a specific speed **up to** the associated product's maximum speed. So when I subscribe to a basic service, I am allowed to put any values between 0 and 500 for my speed configuration.

```cs
public record Product(int Id, string Name, int MaxSpeed);
public record Service(string Name, int ProductId, ServiceConfiguration Configuration);
public record ServiceConfiguration(int Speed, int Other, bool Options, float Whatever);
```

I also have a repository class to provide access to my database:

```cs
public interface IProductRepository
{
    Product GetProductById(int id);
}
```

So now I want to implement validation. I start with a `ServiceValidator`:

```cs
public class ServiceValidator : AbstractValidator<Service>
{
    public ServiceValidator(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        RuleFor(s => s.Name).MaximumLength(50);
        RuleFor(s => s.Configuration)
            .SetValidator(c => new ServiceConfigurationValidator(productRepository));
    }
}
```

I have a constructor here that takes an `IProductRepository`, which is kinda weird since it doesn't really use it, it just needs to pass it on the the `ServiceConfigurationValidator`. Suggestions on how to improve this are welcome.

Then on to my actual question: Let's say I want to validate the following service:

```json
{ 
  "Id": 42,
  "Name": "My subscription Foo Bar",
  "Configuration": {
    "Speed": 10,
    "Other": "Foo",
    "Options": "Bar"
  }
}
```

So I start implementing a `ServiceConfigurationValidator`:

```cs
public class ServiceConfigurationValidator : AbstractValidator<ServiceConfiguration>
{
    public ServiceConfigurationValidator(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        // Use database to retrieve product 42, get it's associated max. speed and ensure the
        // serviceconfiguration value is equal to, or less than, the products max. speed.
    }
}
```

How would I (re)write this `ServiceConfigurationValidator` so that:

1. I can access the ProductId from the "parent" Service
2. I can use that ProductId to retrieve the product from the database using the `IProductRepository` and check that the `Configuration.Speed` doesn't exceed the product's `MaxSpeed`?

I've looked into `PropertyValidators`, gone through [Fluentvalidation's documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/) but I can't for the life of me find anything that points me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Writing a Custom Validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html?highlight=setvalidator#writing-a-custom-validator) is what you need.

**Approach 1: With `.Must()`**

```cs
RuleFor(s => s.Configuration)
    .Must((parent, config, context) =>
    {
        Product product = productRepository.GetProductById(parent.ProductId);
        if (product == null)
        {
            // Handle error for product not existed (if needed)
            context.AddFailure("Product is not existed!");
            return false;
        }

        context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("MaxSpeed", product.MaxSpeed);

        return config.Speed <= product.MaxSpeed;
    })
    .WithMessage("{PropertyName} must be lesser than or equal to {MaxSpeed}.");
```

---

**Approach 2: With `.Custom()`**

```cs
RuleFor(s => s.Configuration)
    .Custom((config, context) =>
    {
        Product product = productRepository.GetProductById(context.InstanceToValidate.ProductId);
        if (product == null)
        {
            // Handle error for product not existed (if needed)
            context.AddFailure("Product is not existed!");
            return;
        }

        if (config.Speed > product.MaxSpeed)
        {
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("PropertyName", nameof(config.Speed));
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("MaxSpeed", product.MaxSpeed);
            context.AddFailure("{PropertyName} must be lesser than or equal to {MaxSpeed}.");
            return;
        }
    });
```

[Demo (Approach 1 & 2) @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SrgX4J)

I don't think that you need to build the custom validator with the `PropertyValidator` abstract class as it is designed for complexity and generic purpose. The above approaches should be enough for your use case.

If you are still keen to implement a custom validator in a separate class, your custom validator class have to [inherit the `PropertyValidator<T, TElement>` abstract class](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html?highlight=setvalidator#reusable-property-validators).

**Approach 3: With `PropertyValidator<T, TElement>`**

```cs
RuleFor(s => s.Configuration)
    .SetValidator(new ServiceConfigurationValidator(productRepository));
```

```cs
public class ServiceConfigurationValidator : PropertyValidator<Service, ServiceConfiguration>
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public ServiceConfigurationValidator(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository; ;
    }


    public override bool IsValid(ValidationContext<Service> context, ServiceConfiguration value)
    {
        Product product = _productRepository.GetProductById(context.InstanceToValidate.ProductId);
        if (product == null)
        {
            // Handle error for product not existed (if needed)
            context.AddFailure("Product is not existed!");
            return false;
        }

        if (value.Speed > product.MaxSpeed)
        {
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("PropertyName", nameof(value.Speed));
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("MaxSpeed", product.MaxSpeed);
            context.AddFailure("{PropertyName} must be lesser than or equal to {MaxSpeed}.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override string Name => "ServiceConfigurationValidator";
}
```

[Demo (Approach 3) @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/77FDIr)

Comment: Aaaah! I see. Thanks! Though it isn't async, but that's ok since that doesn't make sense in an ASP.Net modelvalidation pipeline anyway. This is great, thanks again! I'll award the bounty as soon as I can.